# Multiplying two pandas fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a list of transactions and I would like to take the exec_price field and multiply it with size field so that I can get the total cost.

So, I would like to add a new field: cost = exec_price * size

```
                            date security action  size   ask_price exec_price  \
order_id                                                                    
188      2016-10-24 10:04:44     AAPL    buy     5  116.599998     117.44   
189      2016-10-24 10:04:44     NFLX    buy     5       127.5      128.4   
190      2016-10-24 10:04:44      AMD    buy     5        6.52       6.65   

          status  
order_id          
188       filled  
189       filled  
190       filled
```

When I try to multiple, using:

```
transactions['cost'] = transactions['exec_price'] * transactions['size']
```

I get this:

```
                        date security action  size   ask_price exec_price  \
order_id                                                                    
188      2016-10-24 10:04:44     AAPL    buy     5  116.599998     117.44   
189      2016-10-24 10:04:44     NFLX    buy     5       127.5      128.4   
190      2016-10-24 10:04:44      AMD    buy     5        6.52       6.65   

          status                            cost  
order_id                                          
188       filled  117.44117.44117.44117.44117.44  
189       filled       128.4128.4128.4128.4128.4  
190       filled            6.656.656.656.656.65
```

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because it's a `str` change it to float using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
transactions['exec_price'] = transactions['exec_price'].astype(float)
```

or safer use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to handle any duff values:

```
transactions['exec_price'] = pd.to_numeric(transactions['exec_price'], errors='coerce')
```

When you multiply a str column it just repeats the string contents by that scalar value

Comment: Sweet, that worked! I was doing float(column) earlier and it wasn't working.
Thanks!

Comment: To change the dtype use `astype` if the column type can be safely coerced, otherwise use the in built `to_XXXX` methods as these have better error handling